# PayPal Express Checkout status PaymentActionInProgress

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I can't figure out what the PaymentActionInProgress status means that is returned by the GetExpressCheckoutDetails method of the API.  We see is rarely when compared to the other statuses, but we don't know how to handle it properly.  Currently we consider it a failure and do not call DoExpressCheckout.

Does anyone have some insight about what this status means and how to handle it properly?

https://beta.developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the other statuses in the series, it looks like you've got 4 statuses total

- PaymentActionNotInitiated
- PaymentActionFailed
- PaymentActionInProgress
- PaymentActionCompleted

What this refers to is where the customer is in the Express Checkout(EC) process. In other words, the call also doubles as a way to see what the status of the EC `token` is. `PaymentActionInProgress` means that the customer has started the EC process but you haven't called `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` yet. So, if I were you, I would run that call and see if it succeeds in giving you a payment.